# Android Studio set own install script

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a personal bash script that does some job, installs apk then launches activity, sends broadcasts and does other stuff.

Is it possible to configure Android Studio to start this script instead of doing "adb install" without writing plugins for android studio and doing lots of work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` with either `commandLine` or `executable`.

[Source](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_execute_shell_command_source_or_dot_doestnt_work_with_exec)
[`exec` DSL documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)